# Why does PHP include() not change file access time?

Tags: php, linux, filesystems

Why does PHP `include()` not change file access time? If it matters the system is Debian 4.6.3-14.

Comment: I think that's because including a file does not count as accessing it to the system, the engine reads it as just one big file.

Comment: @AedixRhinedale How would the system know that it is PHP reading the file for including purposes and not some other system reading the file? It's the same read access anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your filesystem has the *relatime* flag set (quite common nowadays) and the file already has access time newer than its modification time, it is not updated. This way there is less writing done on the disk. You can change this by removing that mount option, if you really have a reason to track access times.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. Your post helped me a lot.