# Tools for analyse code usage on production enviroment

Tags: php, analytics, legacy

I develop online shopping system. Currently it runs few hundreds different online stores (on different machines).The code base is developed as one release but each shop instance has own plugins and configuration to adjust system to their custom business needs. The system is being developed for 7 years and it became really big. Due to its age there is a lot of legacy code. I want to figure out which modules/classes are supposed to be deleted. The unnecessary code muddy the water.

I came up with an idea to build "super easy dynamic analysing code usage tool" based on file access time. I assumed that including file in PHP touches it some how. It would be extreamly easy to find out which part of code (whole classes) are not used for years. This woudn't need any libraries integration as xdebug and wouldn't cause any performance hit. Also we have access to historical data (filesystem). But I came accross some difficulties ([Why does PHP include() not change file access time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32026946/why-does-php-include-not-change-file-access-time?noredirect=1#comment51955686_32026946))

Maybe I am inventing the wheel? Maybe there are existing solutions on the market to achieve my goals? I would apprecieate any suggestion. Thanks  you in advance.

Comment: A static analysis tool to detect dead code for PHP is difficult due to the dynamic nature of PHP.    You can use test coverage to determine that some code has not been used for a long time, and then investigate uncovered code.

Comment: At https://www.codacy.com we use the great PHPmd tool that checks for  unused code. It will automatically flag all the unused code in your project. You can find more detail at: https://phpmd.org/rules/unusedcode.html I aslo found https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpdcd that could help